# I want to dynamically hide a series from the chart if the value of that series is 0 for that particular year

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, syncfusion

I want to dynamically hide a series from the chart if the value of that series is 0 for that particular year.

So from the below chart you can see that in year 2020 and above i don't have the actual value so i don't want to show a gap there between both the series

[image]

I tried the below code but it hides all the year actual values. Basically it hides the actual as a whole. I only want if actual value is 0 then dont leave a gap between underwriting and grills

```
 public seriesRender(args: ISeriesRenderEventArgs ): void {
     for (const key in args.data) {
       if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(args.data, key)) {
         const element = args.data[key];         
         if(element.actual == 0 && args.series.name == 'Actual'){
          args.series.chart.visibleSeries.forEach(element => {
            if(element.name == 'Actual')
            element.visible = false;
          });
         }
       }
     }
  }
```

HTML :

```
<e-series-collection>
      <e-series [animation]="animation" [dataSource]='chartData' type='Column' xName='year' yName='underwriting' [name]='underwritingLabel' [marker]='marker'></e-series>
      <e-series [animation]="animation" [dataSource]='chartData' type='Column' xName='year' yName='actual' name='Actual' == 0" [marker]='marker'></e-series>
      <e-series [animation]="animation" [dataSource]='chartData' type='Column' xName='year' yName='grills' name='Grills' [marker]='marker'></e-series>
    </e-series-collection>
```

Comment: visible = false will still take up space in the dom. I don't have enough code to actually give a solid answer. But try collapse (hide also for the dom) or removing the object when it's 0. (This can be done by 'remove element')

Comment: @LotteLemmens I tried visible = false but it hides all the series with actual. Even if i remove the value it will be still showing in the graph because my html looks like above.

Answer (score 0):

As of now it is not possible to skip the empty spaces between the column chart. Since while series calculation we have split the column width equally for all the points based on the number of series rendered. Based per your requirement, if a particular space must be removed, we must modify the column width for the point which will affect the column width of the remaining points too. And, it will not be visually pleasing. Hence this scenario cannot be considered as a feature request.

Let us know if you have any concerns.

Thanks